# Internal NuGet Feed - folder vs IIS

Tags: nuget

Is there a benefit to hosting an internal (remote) NuGet feed through an IIS website vs simply using a shared network folder?

Comment: what do you mean by hosting a internal nuget feed?

Comment: Here's the [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) page on the NuGet site describing the 2 options.  Basically we have internal libraries that we share among multiple projects in our organization.  We want to host those on an internal NuGet feed that developers in our organization can easily use to pull in out librabries.  These are things that we don't want to nor are willing to publish to a public NuGet feed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If shared UNC access is available, then it is definitely the simpler solution to create an internal feed. However, if the feed has a large number of packages, then the performance will be better when using http because of the caching it's able to do. In the UNC case, NuGet needs to crack open the packages on every operation.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the type of comparison I was looking for.